# min time a direct ascent ASAT rocket would take to reach GEO

Tags: orbital-mechanics, geostationary, geosynchronous

Trying to work out a rough time estimate for an ASAT rocket to reach GEO height?

Comment: As far as I know, there are none at present, and nothing very similar either, so you'd probably have to do the design yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to work out the effect on travel time if rocket is fired directly at target rather than needing to enter a stable orbit. It takes hours for a satellite to reach GEO but if a direct ascent is made does that cut it drastically? - to tens of minutes? or is it still hours?

Comment: Assuming you have a rocket that leaves you moving at about 10 km/s practically vertical by the time you are at an altitude of 100 km, you'll coast the rest of the way to GEO in about 6 hours.

Comment: Note my numbers are roughly pulled out of the air since you aren't giving us enough details to properly answer the question!

Comment: Thanks. That is probably enough. I'm just trying to think through the mechanics of missile defences and how potentially strategically destabilising they could be. From what I understand, LEO ground launched ASAT missile could impact with as little as 3-6mins travel time. I just needed to know if an ASAT missile aimed at a GEO satellite would be minutes or hours. -- I'm a International Politics academic working on arguments for a ban on space based weapons. This helps. Thanks

Comment: Kinetic impact ASATs would generate orbital debris. This would be bad for *everyone* having orbital infra-structure, sort of a MAD. DARPA has proposed orbital robots that could do maintenance and salvage of existing sats. If ion propelled, such a robot could rendezvous with many sats. Or extra terrestrial propellent sources could also enable multiple sat rendezvous. Salvage and maintenance bots can loosen as well as tighten a bolt. Ruin or turn a sat *without* the debris cloud. That is the ASAT possibility I worry about.

Comment: @BrianLynch Thanks for the thought provoking example though could you clarify please as I may have misunderstood something? Just to lay it bare. GEO altitude is about 36,000km. At 10km/s thats 36000/10 = 3600 seconds = 1 hour. I'm not saying this would be practical, just curious to see if I have missed something. Does the 6 hour example refer to a GTO trajectory or is that just a co-incidence of the example you chose?

Comment: Thanks for that @HopDavid. Very interesting. They could even steal propellant from the sats they disable. My thinking on the Kessler Syndrome is that particular states that have few satellites wouldn't care and may even use it as a threat. So I'm just trying to work out if ground launched ASAT against GEO and HEO is possible. If not then that removes that problem and changes bargaining positions. But if anyone with ICBM capability could destroy any sat in any orbit then that is very different

Comment: @Matt OK, your thinking is becoming clearer, its an interesting topic. Following your last comment you may at some stage have to put a list of international actors in order as regards which could potentially have a GEO capable missile, whether its called an ICBM or otherwise.  For the moment though such a list would be a research topic in its own right.

Comment: Thanks @Puffin. Yes working out who has a GEO capability now would be a research project in its own right but I'm more interested in thinking through the possibilities and the strategic advantages/pressures 2 or more states with that capability might create. The danger of a Kessler Syndrome is obviously not enough to create cooperation so I need to understand the possibilities that the basic infrastructure of ASAT and hit-to-kill missile defence tech will create (assuming it works at some point in the future) to see if there is an argument for banning weapons that comes from military tactics

Comment: @Matt, you will not be traveling at 10 km/s all the way there, you are starting at that speed and gravity will slow you to a stop just at the point you reach GEO (and then fall back down if you don't have a collision). Just imagine it like you are tossing a ball into the air, it starts with some speed and slows down until reaching the peak and falling back down. Accelerating under propulsive action the entire flight would be a different story, but that is unrealistic in terms of your question and the apparent scope of your work.

Comment: @Matt, I invite you to the Stack Exchange Space Exploration Pod Bay chat room to discuss this further!

Comment: @Matt You might like to consider the separate threat category of the aggressor starting in a stable orbit. I know you wanted to discount that right at the start of this comment thread but there is the possibility that seemingly innocent object, outwardly behaving as a communications satellite could have a dual purpose. It would certainly make the situational awareness difficult to assess. The travel time would be longer though its more a matter of when it starts to deviate from normal behaviour.

Comment: after which... http://spacenews.com/russian-satellite-maneuvers-silence-worry-intelsat/     and   ....  http://spacenews.com/university-taps-air-force-expert-to-launch-space-traffic-effort/

Comment: @Puffin Thanks for the articles. Especially the Russian space based weapons test - or bluff/implied threat maybe. I wasn't aware of that. Many thanks. I'm sure that will make it into the footnotes somewhere.

Comment: @BrianLynch thanks for the invite to the pod bay chat room. I had a read and it seems to be a room for any and all topics in the same room. I'm not sure if I'm breaking any rules or causing problems but if possible I'd rather stay here so I don't need to read through discussions that are unrelated to my question. I'll try and find some time today to think through how I might make my question better or more focused. I really appreciate everyone's input

Comment: @Matt The point of the article about the Russian satellite is that, with no response from the owner other bystanders are left with their imaginations as to its purpose. By nosing around I've picked up various suggestions: supporting naval fleet movements, receiving uplinks from reconnaissance satellites, signals intelligence (perhaps hinted but not stated as monitoring the Intelsat downlink) and if you read the what is and what is not actually stated in this article directly - the ASAT idea is only mentioned by association with other Russian satellites. The point is, one can't tell easily.

Comment: The question can't be answered.  The 6 hour figure above is the maximum time for a rocket that heads straight out, the more rocket you're willing to strap to it the faster it will get there.  With anything resembling current tech the minimum flight time I see is about 5 minutes--but you'll be leaving a major trail of radioactive fire in the process and probably cause some pretty bad EMP effects also.

Comment: @Matt Trying to cut the time below that 6 hours drives the cost up very fast for not all that much gain.  It's unlikely that such a weapon would be built.  The high speed version I gave as a minimum time can only be fired from someplace you don't care about as it's a maximum-performance Orion.  As for the weight--you need a seeker and maneuvering engines.  Any collision at those speeds will destroy a satellite.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Thanks for that. So you think that anything below 4 hours would require massive rockets? like the falcon. What if the proposed SM-3 block 11B is built and its top speed is 7.5m/s. Could that make it to GEO? And how fast? If I use an assumption for scenario building of ASAT to GEO of 3-6 hours is that a reasonable assumption for what could be built in numbers and used by military - so probably small enough for a ship or mobile launcher. Or should it be 4-6 or 1-6?

Comment: China's ASAT test 13th May 2013 is believed to have made it near to GEO. I can't find flight time but it's guessed at over 5 hours. (https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPz5LwyqrKAhUEo5QKHaGjDnIQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thespacereview.com%2Farticle%2F2473%2F1&usg=AFQjCNH4polqt5nZBY_zXFqDbW3izw7Qwg&sig2=oCzbxHrHuCh41kpnnYHn2w&bvm=bv.112064104,d.dGo)

Comment: @Matt Note upthread that he said it takes 10km/sec to reach GEO--anything that can only do 7.5km/sec simply can't get there.  You're looking at something of ICBM size to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

To just intercept the orbit, but not remain there, you can travel at any speed above that required for the [Hohmann transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit).

In other words your travel time can be reduced to as short as you wish, provided you have the fuel and acceleration available.

If you can't handle the maths, you could try some trial-and-error simulations with [Orbiter](http://orbit.medphys.ucl.ac.uk/) for example (just look at the time needed to rise to the altitude you want).

Out of interest (not really an answer), there is a [calculator](http://www.satsig.net/orbit-research/delta-v-geo-injection-calculator.htm) though it only gives the fuel and delta-vee requirements for the Hohmann transfer orbit, not the transfer time.  Also it does not do any calculations for the higher energy case you require.

Comment: "In other words your travel time can be reduced to as short as you wish, provided you have the fuel and acceleration available."   Thanks for that @Andy but isn't there a limit to how much fuel you can carry because of the weight?

Comment: Realistically, you cannot simply accelerate as fast as you want. We can talk about exotic warp drives or just ignore size and cost and pretend we can have a giant ASAT vehicle, but for sensible case studies the most you can expect is a high $Delta v$ manoeuvre sending you into a highly elliptic orbit that sends you to GEO altitude. Someone should consider how fast we could accelerate a Delta IV or Falcon 9 (or maybe even a Saturn V) with no payload.